# JOOQ causing runtime error with Micronaut framework when running on native image

Tags: java, jooq, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have built a project with Micronaut framwork and JOOQ library for database connection that runs with GraalVM native-image. It works fine until I make a request which makes a connection to the database that uses JOOQ library.

This is the error that occurs:

```
14:11:34.486 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] INFO  o.s.j.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory - Default sql-error-codes.xml not found (should be included in spring-jdbc jar)
14:11:34.486 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] ERROR i.m.http.server.RouteExecutor - Unexpected error occurred: Could not construct new record

....

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.smartbits.configurations.jooq.tables.records.UserConfigurationsRecord.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(DynamicHub.java:3349)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(DynamicHub.java:2553)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.recordFactory(Tools.java:900)
    ... 171 common frames omitted
```

I am currently using JOOQ plugin:

```
nu.studer.jooq version '5.2'
```

and the dependency:

```
implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jooq")
```

With GraalVM I have generated the JSON configurations that are needed for the native-image build which are not empty:

```
jni-config.json, reflect-config.json, resource-config.json
```

I want to know if there is a way to run JOOQ on a native-image and automatically generate configuration JSON files for JOOQ classes.

I've made some research and I have tried:

- To manually write reflection configurations for JOOQ (just to test it)
- To add `@Introspected` annotation on JOOQ models

As I noticed, the GraalVM doesn't recognize JOOQ classes to create reflection configurations for them.